# Statistical test for comparing two response options in the same survey item

Tags: statistical-significance, proportion

Is there a way to determine whether the proportion of respondents that endorse one response option of a question is different than the proportion of respondents that endorse another response option of the same question?

For example, suppose my question was "When do you typically experience the most stress during your day?" and the options include "At work," "At home," "It varies," and "Other." I am interested in determining whether the proportion of survey takers that selected "At work" is significantly different from the proportion that selected "At home" (basically ignoring the other two categories). Is that possible?

Comment: Are you leaning toward any methods?  Are you stuck on some particular aspect of the problem?

Comment: @ronaldo2 I know how to compare proportions of two different items, I am just not sure how do compare proportions of two options for the same item. Right now, I am considering creating two dichotomous dummy variables. Using the example above, one variable would have a value of "1" for "At work" and "0" for everything else, while the second variable would have a "1" for "At home" and a "0" for everything else. Then comparing the proportions (means) of those two variables. I'm not sure if that is the right direction though.

Comment: OK, I think I have come up with a solution (much simpler than I initially thought). I created a confidence interval around each proportion using the following formula: CI = z*SqRt((p*(1-p))/n); where z = 1.96 (for 95% confidence interval), p = proportion, and n = sample size. I add and subtract the CI from the proportion to get the range of the confidence interval. As long as the two confidence intervals do not overlap, I can make the claim that the proportions are significantly different. Hopefully that makes sense, and if anyone else runs into a similar situation, they can find their answer.

Comment: I think you are nearly correct--the fly in the ointment is the fact that the 2 proportions are ipsative.  So my approach would be to use the chi-square test instead.  It's not compromised by the "zero-sum-game" aspect of the data because it tests for unevenness in the single distribution that contains all the response options.